# AngularJS Multiple ng-repeats on single row of table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to display a table with items from both a parent and a list of child objects.  Is it possible to do this using ng-repeat?   A for loop would look something like this.

```
foreach(var parent in list)
  foreach (var child in parent)
     print(parent.1)
     print(parent.2)
     print(child.1)
     print(child.2)
```

Below is the general idea of what each row would look like.

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="parent in list">
   ng-repeat="child in parent"
    <td>parent.item1</td>
    <td>parent.item2</td>
    <td>parent.item3</td>
    <td>child.item1</td>
    <td>child.item2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: not much clear..could you explain it more..

Comment: that's still not really clear; the inner `ng-repeat` needs an element... are you intending to nest the child `<tr>` inside the parent `<tr>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, quite possible.

Assuming an array of `parent` objects called `parents` and that `parent.child` itself is an array of `child` objects, as it seems to be in your example, you would then do the following using the special ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end forms of ngRepeat.

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="parent in parents">  
    <td>parent.item1</td>
    <td>parent.item2</td>
    <td>parent.item3</td>
    <td ng-repeat-start="child in parent.child">child.item1</td> <!-- start of the inner loop -->
    <td ng-repeat-end>child.item2</td> <!-- end of inner loop -->
</tr>
</table>
```

**Update:**

Since the OP seems to want separate child rows grouped by parent, this might be the solution sought:

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="parent in parents">
  <tr ng-repeat="child in parent.child">
    <td>parent.item1</td>
    <td>parent.item2</td>
    <td>parent.item3</td>
    <td>child.item1</td>
    <td>child.item2</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: that will only make one row for each parent, with multiples of the child `<td>`, yes?  so if a parent has 5 children, there will be 10 `<td>` in that row?

Comment: Ah, I see what you are looking for.   Let me change the code a bit.

Comment: @james Try this update. Do either of these get you what you want?

Comment: I got the first example to work but as @Claies stated it only dones one row per parent and I need a row per child.

Comment: @MichaelOryl The second example seems to do what I want but I am currently getting another error.

Comment: The issue seems to be that Angular DataTables do not support multiple <tbody> tags.

Comment: @James That's a shame.  It's perfectly legal for a table to have multiple tbody tags.  Your issue is that you need nested tags to get the nested ng-repeats that you require.

Comment: @MichaelOryl It is a shame but I am able to just switch to regular datatables and make it work.