# Filter first value of array inside ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can i filter `josn` first element of a row inside `ng-repeat` using `angularjs`.
i am stuck with this.

My sample code is::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 <body>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="x in num| orderBy:'n'">
     <b>{{x.n}}</b>
     <div ng-repeat="y in amt | orderBy:'v'">
       <div ng-if="x.n==y.n">
         <div>{{y.v}}</div>
       </div>
      </div >
    <br />
    </div>
<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.num= [
    {n:'3'},
    {n:'1'},
    {n:'2'},
    ];

$scope.amt= [
    {n:'1',v:'23'},
    {n:'1',v:'24'},
    {n:'1',v:'45'},
    {n:'2',v:'56'},
    {n:'2',v:'67'},
    {n:'2',v:'45'},
    {n:'3',v:'23'},
    {n:'3',v:'67'},
    {n:'3',v:'19'},
    ];

 });
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Result is 
 **1**
23
24
45

**2**
45
56
67

**3**
19
23
67

I am result only. first value.

like:
**1**
23
**2**
45
**3**
19

Please help...

Comment: this strategy is really inefficient: it loops through the whole `amt` array for each x.n, only to display a single element. Why don't you find the elements that you want to display in the JS code, just once?

Comment: Please refer this link may be useful to you.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570661/angularjs-multiple-ng-repeats-on-single-row-of-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570661/angularjs-multiple-ng-repeats-on-single-row-of-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create custom filter function:

```
$scope.myFilter = function (x) {
  return function (y) {
    if (x.n==y.n) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
};
```

Use it in inner ng-repeat:

```
 <div ng-repeat="y in amt | orderBy:'v' | filter:myFilter(x) | limitTo:1">
   <div>{{y.v}}</div>
 </div >
```

Also, to get top 1 result add standard limitTo filter (limitTo:1), wich first argument sets max return count.

Comment: This is perfect for me.. and this code solve my multiple problem... thanks Slava

Answer (score 0):

`(...)
    < /tr>
        < /thead>
        < tbody>
          < tr ng-repeat="object in objects | SOME_FILTER">
            (...)
            {{object.get("element")}}
            {{(object.get("element2")).innerElement}}
            (...)
          < /tr>
        < /tbody>
      < /table>
    (...)`

The 3 dots means that there was some code cut out. "element2" is the one with a JSON inside. "innerElement" is the key. it worked for me, hope would be useful to someone

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Try to format the code properly and maybe add some more explanation