# AngularJS Multiple ng-repeats on single row of table - Extended

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is the extended question of [AngularJS Multiple ng-repeats on single row of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570661/angularjs-multiple-ng-repeats-on-single-row-of-table)

I'm trying to display a grandChilds collection. A for loop would look something like this.

```
foreach(var parent in list)
  foreach (var child in parent)
    foreach (var grandChild in child)
     print(grandChild.item1)
     print(grandChild.item2)
     print(grandChild.item3)
```

Below is the general idea of what each row would look like.

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="parent in list">
   ng-repeat="child in parent"
     ng-repeat="grandChild in child"
        <td>grandChild.item1</td>
        <td>grandChild.item2</td>
        <td>grandChild.item3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In the above referred question, `TBODY` is a good idea. But it will satisfy only two level (i.e., Parent and Child). How could I achieve my requirement (Parent, Child, Grandchild). Kindly assist me.

If I use nested `TBODY`, then its **failed** in the **W3C Validation**.

Kindly assist me how to achieve this

Comment: please mention data sample in question

Comment: @NIKHILRANE sure... Kindly wait I will update it.

Answer (score 0):

Use new table for each parent.

```
<table ng-repeat="parent in list">
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="child in parent">
        <td ng-repeat="grandchild in child"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Grandchild is a collection of object.

Comment: Angular will still loop through each object keys. Else you can use what you already did. <td>grandChild.item1</td>
        <td>grandChild.item2</td>
        <td>grandChild.item3</td>

Comment: I know, how to organize the html table structure based on W3C ?

Answer (score 0):

You could show a table(or other elements such as span\div) for grandchild collection within the table for list

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="parent in list">
    <td ng-repeat="child in parent">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="grandChild in child">
              <td ng-repeat="item in grandChild">
                {{item}}
              <td>
             </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr></table>
```

EDIT: I have replaced it with div element. You can work on how to order the data in the display.

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="parent in list">
    <td ng-repeat="child in parent">
        <div ng-repeat="grandChild in child">
            <div ng-repeat="item in grandChild">
                {{item}}
            </div>
        </div>          
    </td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: Is there is any other way to avoid nested Table ? I will wait for some time, so no answer is posted, then I will mark your answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can also use ul (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp)